# node-bcrypt compile error

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm fully aware that this is probably my fault (mostly for using Gentoo), but I'm stuck so if there is something I'm not seeing or a short coming I've found please sound in.

```
make: Entering directory /home/* * */sites/disc/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> {anonymous}::GenerateSalt(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:257:74: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*) {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*)}’ to ‘uv_after_work_cb {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/* * */.node-gyp/0.9.9/deps/uv/include/uv.h:1393:15: error: initializing argument 4 of ‘int uv_queue_work(uv_loop_t*, uv_work_t*, uv_work_cb, uv_after_work_cb)’ [-fpermissive]
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> {anonymous}::Encrypt(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:337:74: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*) {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*)}’ to ‘uv_after_work_cb {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/* * */.node-gyp/0.9.9/deps/uv/include/uv.h:1393:15: error: initializing argument 4 of ‘int uv_queue_work(uv_loop_t*, uv_work_t*, uv_work_cb, uv_after_work_cb)’ [-fpermissive]
../src/bcrypt_node.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> {anonymous}::Compare(const v8::Arguments&)’:
../src/bcrypt_node.cc:431:74: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(uv_work_t*) {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*)}’ to ‘uv_after_work_cb {aka void (*)(uv_work_s*, int)}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/* * */.node-gyp/0.9.9/deps/uv/include/uv.h:1393:15: error: initializing argument 4 of ‘int uv_queue_work(uv_loop_t*, uv_work_t*, uv_work_cb, uv_after_work_cb)’ [-fpermissive]
make: * * * [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory/home/***/sites/disc/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
```

Any advice as to why this is failing?  Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Comment: the error message may be trying to tell you that the error will only become a warning if you add "-fpermissive" to gcc options.  Not familiar with bcrypt node module, but I'd try to add this option to compile the native code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is in the node version.  I was using 0.9.9 and as soon as I reverted back to 0.9.3 it compiled just fine.

Comment: Actually, it was an out of date npm version.  The fine devs of the bcrypt module did a quick update of the npm version and we were good to go.